# Express nodejs req.body returns undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying a simple form submission code, and I'm using post method.
My server.js code

```
//N-4E;V-56;I-49
//var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var idx = require('./index.js');
var ra = require('./ra.js');

var app = express();

app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 5649);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use('/',idx);

app.use('/reg_path',ra);

app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log('Express started press asdfadsfasdfasdf');
    });
```

my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    //res.sendHeader(.)
    res.render('index.ejs',{});
    //res.render('title.ejs',{});
    });

module.exports = router;
```

my index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    </body>
    <div id="reg_path">
      <p>Enter the Regressions Folder Path</p>
      <form action="/reg_path" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="path">Path:</label>
      <input type="text" id="path" name="path" placeholder="Enter the     Absolute path"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
    </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my ra.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express.Router();
var path;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.path);
    path = req.body.path;
    fs.access('path',fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect('./index');
        //if (err) {
        //  res.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
        //    return res.end('The specified path "' + path + '" does not     exists');
        //}
    });
    //fs.access('path',fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
    //  //if (err) {
    //  //  res.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    //  //  return res.end('The specified path "' + path + '" has no READ     permissions');
    //  //}
    //});
});



module.exports = app;
```

Now, from the index page, when I type a path in the form, and press the submit, in the console.log the 'req.body' is returned as 'undefined'.

most of the code in ra.js is commented or not updated because the 'req.body' value is unavailable in the first place. I need to correct it first.

I've searched through internet to try and figure out the mistake that is in my code, but to my vain I'm unable to uncover it. Any help is much appreciated

node version:v6.11.0

body-parser :1.17.2
express :4.15.3
ejs :2.5.6

Comment: server.js is missing app.use(bodyParser.json()); and you don't need body parser ra.js whatever that file is ^_^. If you are new to ExpressJS I would recommend using this template https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator-dg - and take it from there, every line of code is explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form uses `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which is an encoding type that `body-parser` doesn't support.

If you need to use this type (for instance, if you're going to be uploading files from your form), take a look at [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Otherwise, leave out the `enctype` attribute so the form will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Thank you. I've removed enctype attribute, and it resolved my issue. The form contains only one entry (input) so the enctype attribute is not required.